# How to bind Opacity value based on opacity of the object from another ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I’d like to find out how to bind the opacity of the object that is part of the ControlTemplate to the object that is part of another ControlTemplate.
I tried this but it is not doing anything.

```
Image x:Name="PART_IconHover" Source="{Binding IconHover}" Opacity="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=border, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Below is the code of two ControlTemplates:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="#FF6E6E6E" BorderThickness="0.5" Opacity="0" Background="#00000000">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true"/>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
```

I want to bind the opacity to the image in the ControlTemplate below

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ThumbnailContainerTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Border x:Name="PART_Border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFd9d9d9" Opacity="0" />
    <Grid Margin="10">   
            <Image x:Name="PART_IconHover" Source="{Binding IconHover}" Opacity="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=border, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
```

Any ideas are highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mdm20 said, you can't bind to elements inside templates from outside the template since a template is just used to build up a control. For instance, several Buttons could use the Template in your example so which Button would the ContentControl bind to?

I can't see a re-usable solution to this but one thing that comes to mind is to set the Binding in code behind once the Controls have finished loading like this

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Border border = myButton.Template.FindName("border", myButton) as Border;
    Image PART_IconHover = contentControl.Template.FindName("PART_IconHover", contentControl) as Image;

    Binding opacityBinding = new Binding("Opacity");
    opacityBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    opacityBinding.Source = border;
    PART_IconHover.SetBinding(Image.OpacityProperty, opacityBinding);
}
```

**Update**
Two Controls binding to the border in a Button template. The binding is made in the Control_Loaded event handler.

```
<ContentControl ...
                Loaded="Control_Loaded">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource contentTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
<ContentControl ...
                Loaded="Control_Loaded">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource contentTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>

private void Control_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Border border = myButton.Template.FindName("border", myButton) as Border;
    Control control = sender as Control;
    Image PART_IconHover = control.Template.FindName("PART_IconHover", control) as Image;

    Binding opacityBinding = new Binding("Opacity");
    opacityBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    opacityBinding.Source = border;
    PART_IconHover.SetBinding(Image.OpacityProperty, opacityBinding);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is a valid point. I will try to implement it in my sample. I will let you know if I will be successful.

Comment: @vladc77: Yes, hopefully it will! The code I posted is from a sample app of your problem that I made and it worked for me. It's not a very dynamic solution but if you just need this in a place or two then that should'n be a problem :)

Comment: I need to have this behavior on dynamically created control. My only worry is if it will change the opacity on other controls that were created on run time.

Comment: @vladc77: This only effects the control ContentControl called "contentControl". To control exatcly which controls get this behavior you can add a "Control_Loaded" event which you hook up all the controls that needs this opacity binding to and then you use the sender object instead of the hard coded "contentControl". Did I understand your worries corretly? :)

Comment: Yes, you undrestood it correctly. Thank you for help. I am wondering you you wouldn't mind you show any sample of "Control_loaded" event that you described. I think this is what I need. Thank you.

Comment: @vladc77: Updated my example. It's basically the same thing, just moved the event. Every control that has a part called PART_IconHover in its Template can use this

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can bind to elements inside templates like that.  The binding system isn't able to find them.

If you just need a numeric value somewhere in your xaml that you want everything to use, you can just add one like this:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="Opacity">.5</sys:Double>
```

Then just have everything bind to that.  You'll need to add the sys namespace

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: Thank you for looking. I need to change the opacity of the image inside the second Controltemplate when MouseOver happens over the first ControlTemplate. On MouseOver, the storyboard inside the first ControlTemplate is initiated to run. I am not sure if I can do it with the solution you provided. Any ideas about the right way to do it? Thank you.